# How to assign value to destination property on aftermap in automapper

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

I have these classes

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public string SubjectIds { get; set; } //Comma delimited string of subject ID
    public string Grades { get; set; } //Comma delimited string of subject ID
}


public class StudentListItemDto
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int StudentName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SubjectGradeDto> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class SubjectGradeDto 
{
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

In my mapping profile I have this where I map `IEnumerable<Student>` to `List<StudentListItemDto>`:

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<Student>, List<StudentListItemDto>>()
        .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
            {
                List<StudentListItemDto> iStudentListItemDto;
                iStudentListItemDto= src.Select(p =>
                  new StudentListItemDto
                  {
                      StudentId= p.StudentId,
                      StudentName= p.Name,
                      Tags = p.SubjectIds!= null ? p.SubjectIds.Split(",").Select((tag, i) => new SubjectGradeDto { SubjectIds= int.Parse(tag), Grade= p.Grades.Split(",")[i] }) : null
                  }).ToList();
                dest = iStudentListItemDto; // I'm assigning values to destination
            });
```

The reason why I am mapping it this ways is because I need to map Subjects and Grades property of Students class, which is are comma delimited values to `IEnumerable<SubjectGradeDto>`

Further improvement to the mapping would be much appreciated.

But my problem is when I am assigning

```
dest = iStudentListItemDto;
```

in the AfterMap. When I debug it, it has a value, but when the mapping gets executed here

```
IEnumerable<StudentListItemDto> iStudentListItemDto= new List<StudentListItemDto>();
        iStudentListItemDto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Student>, IEnumerable<StudentListItemDto>>(searchResult, iStudentListItemDto);
```

where search result is `IEnumerable<Student>`

`iStudentListItemDto` evaluates to empty List.

The question is why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `CreateMap` your mapping `IEnumerable` to `List` and when effectively mapping you are mapping from `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable`.

List is IEnumerable, but IEnumerable is not a List, basically.

With this mapping you created you only have the direction from IEnumerable to List.

A better approach, as I can see you are only using this way for mapping the tags, is to do something like this

```
CreateMap<Student, StudentListItemDto>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.StudentName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.Tags, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .AfterMap((student, dto) =>
            {
                dto.Tags = student.SubjectIds!= null ? student.SubjectIds.Split(",").Select((tag, i) => new SubjectGradeDto { SubjectIds= int.Parse(tag), Grade= student.Grades.Split(",")[i] }) : null;
            });
```

Now if AutoMapper sees that you are mapping a single object or a list of these objects, it will map each object of this list correctly.

This because you are not using the whole list to create this list of Tags.

Comment: How do I get p.SubjectIds though. VS doesn't recognize p

Comment: sorry, my bad. Hehehe.
`p` should be the student you are trying to map.
I just changed the names from `src`/`dest` to `student`/`dto` so it can be more visible the mapping direction. :)